# WooCommerce Tax - wrong automatic calculation problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tax-rate

I have the following issue with VAT Tax calculations in WooCommerce. Here is some preliminary information:

- Standard VAT Tax rates are entered as follows: WooCommerce > Settings > Tax > Standard Rate (attached image)[image]
- VAT Tax settings are configured (attached images) for automatic tax calculation based on the entered shipping address.[image][image][image]

Everything seems to be set up and entered correctly.

THE PROBLEM:
When I complete an order for a product and enter an address without specifying any country for both billing and shipping (same address),
WooCommerce does not correctly calculate VAT Tax. It constantly creates new entries in the "Standard Tax rate" table with incorrect information.
For example, if I select Germany instead of the original 19% entered in the table, WooCommerce creates a new entry in the "DE DE-BY 20.000 DE-BY TAX" table, and instead of calculating it at 19%, it calculates it at 20%, which is incorrect. If I enter Finland, where VAT Tax is 24%, WooCommerce again creates a new entry with 20% and calculates it at 20%.
The address of the online store is in Bulgaria, where VAT Tax is 20%, and I thought there might be some connection to what is happening, but I can't figure out where things are going wrong.

Please provide information on where the problem might be and possibly how to fix it. Because it concerns the OSS system where VAT Tax should be automatically calculated for the countries where the goods will be shipped.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your last image. What options do you have in the "Default customer location" dropdown? Have you checked the [documentation and done the troubleshooting?](https://woo.com/document/woocommerce-shipping-and-tax/)

Comment: Default custom location - the options are as follow:
- No location by default
- Shop country/region
- Geolocate
- Geolocate (with page caching support)

Comment: can you try and disable automated tax from your second image? There it also tells you some important information, and you can find more in the [woocommerce tax guide](https://woo.com/document/woocommerce-shipping-and-tax/woocommerce-tax/#:~:text=To%20enable%20automated%20tax%20calculation,automated%20taxes%E2%80%9D%20and%20Save%20Changes.). _"When Automated taxes are in use, this overrides **any tax rates** you have manually added for locations where you have a tax nexus, as well as the “Compound” and “Shipping” toggles for those tax rates."_